# Android: passing a value from database to contsant/variable

Tags: android, database, variables

I seem to be returning a value from a database for the column id #, but I want the actual text value of a column I have already defined.

I have a String defined as ID_COLUMN_TITLE, which is where I am trying to pass the value of the column to the string.:

```
public final static String ID_COLUMN_TITLE = "com.pocketbeta.COLUMN_TITLE";
```

The COLUMN_TITLE value is populated by the database in a different snippet of code:

```
public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "route_name";
```

Next I set up the adapter and listener, and pass it to an activity:

```
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i=new Intent(SmithRockNameDatabase.this, DatabaseChoice.class);
        i.putExtra(ID_COLUMN_TITLE, String.valueOf(id));
        startActivity(i);
    }
};
```

Then the new activity displays the result:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.databasechoice);
passedVar=getIntent().getStringExtra(SmithRockNameDatabase.ID_COLUMN_TITLE);
    passedView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.passed);
    passedView.setText(passedVar);
}
```

Everything is working, only it displays the column ID and not the actual value of the column title as I want.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Do you get a correct output if you log the value of id in the ClickListener?

Comment: you are putting the valueOf(id) in the key- ID_COLUMN_TITLE. What you will get back is valueOF(id). Is that what you want? or do you want ID_COLUMN_TITLE?

Comment: Yeah, I recognized the passing of the id from the valueOf(id) right after I posted.  I'm trying to pass the value of one of the columns entries.  So for instance, I am trying to pass the value of 1 entry in the column named "route_name" in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution to this is to grab the text from the view:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    Intent i=new Intent(SmithRockNameDatabase.this, DatabaseChoice.class);

    // I use R.id.txtTitle here but you probably have something similar
    TextView txtTitle = (TextView)view.findViewByid(R.id.txtTitle);
    if(txtTitle!=null)i.putExtra(ID_COLUMN_TITLE, txtTitle.getText());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Strictly speaking though you should probably use the id in your new activity to query the data relating to that id, then you have access to all fields in the record.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get to, I think this works.  Thanks!

Comment: I missed the cast to `TextView` ... I keep doing that. Fixed now though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Everything you do works as it should.

Your doing this line:

```
i.putExtra(ID_COLUMN_TITLE, String.valueOf(id));
```

Which is converting an int into a string so on your next activity the text is set to this int.

I think your looking to do something more like:

```
  String value = (view.findViewById(R.id.text1)).getText();
  i.putExtra(ID_COLUMN_TITLE, String.valueOf(id));
```

I'm not too sure what text you want to get but the basic answer is your converting an int to a string. So 4 = "4" then your displaying that. Your missing the step of getting the actual text you want.